# xAxis label is displayed outside the box

Tags: javascript, angular, canvasjs

I have a strange behavior.
the chart (line) is displayed all well, but the X axis labels (dates or time and date) are displayed on the left of the tick and not below it as it should be. I have tried all possible settings, but nothing helps. the tick is displayed in the right location, and the box of the label (colored in red) is displayed in the right location but the content of the label is on the left side.
this is the settings for the X axis:

```
    axisX: {
         interval: 3600 * 3,
         gridColor: 'lightgrey',
         tickColor: 'lightgrey',
         labelFormatter: e => {
              if(e.chart.axisX[0].dataInfo.max - e.chart.axisX[0].dataInfo.min > (86400000 * 5))
                                return moment(e.value).format('D.M');
                            else
                                return moment(e.value).format('HH:mm D.M');
         },
         crosshair: {
             enabled: true,
             color: '#244D85',
             snapToDataPoint: false,
             label: ''
         },
         lineColor: 'transparent',
         labelFontSize: 15,
         labelAngle: 0,
         margin: 10,
         labelBackgroundColor: '#942626',
         labelAutoFit:true,
         labelWrap: true,
    }
```

I have deliberately set the label background to red , so it will be more visible (the problem).
Image is attached to show the problem.
Please help, I'm out of ideas.

[image]

Comment: It seems to be working fine, take a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/462tmvrx/)

Comment: I have found the problem, it was the dir="rtl" on the body tag. seems the canvasJS has a problem with it and result with unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Can you check JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/462tmvrx/) that I've shared in previous comment? In that JSFiddle I've set direction rtl for body tag itself and it seems to be working fine. Can you share your code that reproduces the issue, so that I can understand your case better?